# Loading images with aframe

Tags: aframe

Newbie here so a pre-emptive apology if I am not using the correct language or referring to the correct things.

I am using the code below to load a 360image as my scene.

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets> 
    <img id="skyTexture" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Hellbrunn_banqueting_hall_360_panoramic_view.jpg"> 
  </a-assets>

  <a-sky src="#skyTexture"></a-sky>....
```

And all is well. However, when I test it takes a while to load and this message is repeated in the console.

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is incomplete
```

Eventually, it loads (sometimes!)

When i look for an explanation of the error online, the search gives me other options of loading an image but I can't quite get my head around it. Is there a sample piece of code to see how I can preload using another method?

Thanks in advance

S

Answer (score 0):

Your image has not yet loaded when the `<a-sky>` entity is invoked.

Have a look at [the A-Frame documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/asset-management-system.html), you'll find an example there. You need to wrap the `<img>` with an `<a-assets>` tag so A-Frame can make sure to load it before creating your sky.

Comment: Your image is almost 20MB big. Two ideas: serve the file locally or use a smaller version, I tried 1280px successfully.

Comment: Yeah that's fair enough, guess what I am wondering is if there is some preloader code for times when the connection is slow or the image is big